# date-fns get duration in hh:mm format (minutes in 100 unit based)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, date-fns

I'm build a time logging utilities for myself as a project to get better with vuejs and JavaScript. user can enter multiple task entries. Each task consist of:

- start (as a time picker) {return a Date object} [task.start]
- end (as a time picker) {return a Date object} [task.end]
- other fields...

What I want to do when I display my list of task, is to show the duration of the task on the format of ***hh:ss***.

- hh = the number of hours 0 to infinite (can go over 24 hours, like 26)
- ss = the number of minutes on a base of 100. Example, 15 minutes  = 25

Final output would like this:

start / end / result

November 17th, 2022 08:00 / November 17th, 2022 09:15 / **1:25**

November 17th, 2022 08:00 / November 17th, 2022 11:45 / **3:75**

November 17th, 2022 08:00 / November 17th, 2022 8:30 / **0:50**

November 17th, 2022 08:00 / November 18th, 2022 11:00 / **27:00**

I have succeeded to get that result, but I don't think the way i did it is efficient / the best way:

```
import { differenceInSeconds, intervalToDuration } from "date-fns";

const zeroPad = (num) => String(num).padStart(2, '0');

const getDuration = (task) => {
    const rawDuration = intervalToDuration({start: 0, end: differenceInSeconds(task.end, task.start) * 1000});
    return `${rawDuration.hours}:${zeroPad((rawDuration.minutes/60)*100)}`;
};
```

I would like like to use date-fns library on this project since it is smaller than moment.js and I already use it for other date manipulation. But I am willing to switch over to moment.js if needed. I would be also open to vanilla js if it do not need much more code.

I will continue to try to find a solution on my end, I will update this post if I find anything better than what I have done.

Thanks.